# ¿Cómo sé la distribución que siguen unos datos?

Tags: r

Estoy intentando conocer que distribución sigue un conjunto de datos. Los datos están relacionados con acontecimientos poco probables, por lo que pensé que podría ser una Poisson, pero parece ser que no, según los resultados.

La tabla de frecuencias es la siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He usado goodfit y mínimos cuadrados:

`ajuste <- goodfit(risk, type = 'poisson',  method = 'MinChisq')`

Y en el summary me ha salido esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He visto que en el ajuste me ha salido el `count 0`. La serie sólo es de 1 a 5. No entiendo cómo ha salido eso.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo puedo solucionar esto y qué debo hacer para saber qué distribución pueden seguir los datos?

Comment: Bienvenido Jack a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Comment: Creo que esta pregunta es más para https://stats.stackexchange.com/ que para este sitio, de hecho, hay un buena respuesta al respecto que tal vez te sirva: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/132652/how-to-determine-which-distribution-fits-my-data-best

Answer (score 0):

bienvenido/a,

en mi experiencia para seleccionar una distribución y utilizarla para modelar/simular una variable es más importante lo que sabemos del *proceso generador de datos* (PGD) que la distribución numérica de la variable observada.

¿Por qué no es confiable la distribución observada? Asumo que estamos hablando de variables aleatorias extraídas de una población (o producidas por un PGD con componente alatorio) y que quieres saber si la población que produjo esa variable tiene una distribución *D* para esa variable. Como la variable medida por muestreo es aleatoria bien puede (aunque con baja probabilidad) ubicarse en una de las colas de la distribución y presentar en su medición empírica unas características consistentes con una distribución diferente de aquella de la que provienen. En un caso muy extremo y poco probable tus datos podría provenir de una distribución normal en la que (por azar) sólo se muestrearon enteros, sesgados a la izquierda. Entonces tus datos *se ven como si fueran* provenientes una distribución de Poisson con lambda = 4, cuando en realidad no lo son.

¿Por qué es importante el PGD? Porque en general conociendo el PGD podemos saber qué supuestos distribucionales se cumples y cuales no. Por ejemplo, si en tu variable 153 es el total de eventos posibles, entonces sería conveniente modelarla como una distribución multinomial, ya que puedes estimar la proporción de 1, 2 o 3. Si 153 no es el total de eventos posibles, sino solamente los observados en tus "parcelas" entonces sería más apropiado asumir una distribución de Poisson (o binomial negativa o alguna por el estilo). Eso no puedes saberlo mirando solo los números o haciendo pruebas de hipótesis. Es necesario como se produjeron los datos, que miden y como.

Por último: creo que la distribución asumimos para nuestros datos depende más de lo que queremos analizar y de las propiedades matemáticas aprovechables de cada distribución que de la "verdadera" distribución de la variable. No usamos distribuciones normales porque en el mundo haya fenómenos que tienen una distribución normal: lo hacemos porque con dos datos (media y varianza) podemos hacer estimaciones de errores, simulaciones de datos, etc. y resolverlos matemáticamente de forma fácil, integrando debajo de una curva o con álgebra lineal.

El problema de tener supuestos erróneos sobre la distribución de nuestras variables aparece con frecuencia cuando estamos haciendo un modelo que *tiene supuestos distribucionales*. Entonces la pregunta no es tanto ¿a qué distribución corresponde mi variable? sino ¿puedo usarla en el modelo *M*? Eso restringe la pregunta y hace más fácil responderla.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Los datos son relativos a un índice que expresa si hay mucha o poca posibilidad de que ocurra un fenómeno meteorológico. Generalmente se suele hablar de Poisson, de ahí que desde el inicio se considerara. Sin embargo como ya se ha visto no es así. Debería encontrar una solución a este problema, pero no veo por donde tirar.